# Flot Pie Chart with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, flot

I tried to add load a Pie Chart dynamically using Flot Chart and PHP/MySQL.

This is my javascript code

```
 <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


  function fetchData() {
   $.ajax({
      url:      "test.php",
      method:   "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success:  function(series) {
         var data = [  series ];
         $.plot($("#graph1"), data, {
            pie: { 
                show: true,
                showLabel: true
            },
            legend: {
                show: false 
            }
        });
      }
   });

   setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);
}


$(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function(){
    fetchData();                       
  });   

});
```

This is my PHP Code

```
<?php 
    include("db.php");
    $return_arr = array();
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT item, COUNT(target) FROM counter WHERE type='video' and date BETWEEN '2011-02-21' and '2011-02-26' GROUP BY target ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
        $return_arr[] = $obj;   
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

This is my button

```
<input type="submit" value="click" id="btn"/>
```

This is the array that I get when I click the button

```
[{"item":"Final 2010","COUNT(target)":"2"},{"item":"Semi Final 2009","COUNT(target)":"3"}]
```

When I click the button, it gives me this error:

```
An invalid or illegal string was specified" code: "12
[Break On This Error] false
```

and Even the pie chart is not loading. Can anybody tell me where did I made the wrong.

When I check in firebug, the array is showing like this

```
[{"item":"Final 2010","COUNT(target)":"2"},{"item":"Semi Final 2009","COUNT(target)":"3"}]
```

But when I print it, it shows as [Object object][Object object], I think that would be the problem, anyone know how to fix it

Thanks

Comment: your json string is prefect , i checked on `jslint.com`, u shoud use `json_decode`..it may help..btw wat u want to display/retrieve and in which way

Comment: also use alias for `COUNT(target)` in mysql query like  `SELECT item, COUNT(target) AS totalTarget FROM counter WHERE type='video' and date BETWEEN '2011-02-21' and '2011-02-26' GROUP BY target ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: @diEcho I want to show the visitor percentage for a set of pages in my application. Thanks for the alias thing, I'll add it. I'll try with the json_decode too

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to eval that data (series)

```
var data    = eval("(" + series + ")");
```

That should do it, I think

**EDIT**

Added a simple replication on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TVAWL/1/

Comment: No, what I meant is that you're getting a string representation of an array (JSON). adding that line instead of your var data ... line should solve your problem. Did you try it?

Comment: @JohnP : Yest I tried it, but its not working, when I check with firebug, it gives - " missing ] after element list ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object "

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the JSON you're returning. And when you eval it, it comes correctly (see this : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/aey64/). Can you paste the code you're currently using? And you've completely replaced `var data = [  series ];` with `var data    = eval("(" + series + ")");` ?

Comment: @JohnP: This is my current code - <pre><code><script type="text/javascript">
  
  
  
  
$(function () {
  $("#btn").click(function(){
   fetchData();        
    });
  
  function fetchData() {
   $.ajax({
      url:      "test.php",
      method:   "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success:  function(series) {
   
  
         var data = [series];
   alert(data);
         $.plot($("#graph1"), data, {
   pie: { 
    show: true,
    showLabel: true
   },
   legend: {
    show: false 
   }
  });
      }
   });

   setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);
}
});

</script></pre></code>

Comment: You still haven't replaced it with my code. You need to replace `var data = [series]` with `var data    = eval("(" + series + ")");`. Try that please

Comment: did it, still the same error, here's the code - $(function () {
  $("#btn").click(function(){
   fetchData();        
    });
  
  function fetchData() {
   $.ajax({
      url:      "test.php",
      method:   "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success:  function(series) {
    
  var data = eval("(" + series + ")");
         
         $.plot($("#graph1"), data, {
   pie: { 
    show: true,
    showLabel: true
   },
   legend: {
    show: false 
   }
  });
      }
   });

   setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);
} });
</script>

Comment: Can you look at this example please : http://jsfiddle.net/TVAWL/1/ I replicated your code and it works when I do the replacement.

Comment: Now the errors has gone, but the chart is not showing :( I'll check it Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any other easily pluggable jquery or php charts available for load data dynamically. Please share to me

Comment: I use Flot, and I've done exactly what you do without any issue. But there are lots more : http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/