# Parse data from php to jsquery.flot.pie

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flot

I've seen some questions about this already but I still couldn't clear the fog around this...

I have this sql statement to get data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


<?php

$query = "SELECT rel_id, SUM(suma) FROM $tbl_rel_balansas INNER JOIN $tbl_balansas ON $tbl_rel_balansas.rel_id = $tbl_balansas.id WHERE $tbl_rel_balansas.member_id = '$_SESSION[id]'";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo 'var some_data = ' . json_encode( $viso );
}


?>
```

Next is the js part:

```
    $(function () {


   $.plot($("#placeholder"), [some_data], 
{
        series: {
            pie: { 
                show: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        }
});
});
</script>
```

I was thinking I could reach the data in some_data and use it to display it in the pie chart, unfortunately this is not the way to go.

Any help and suggestions are greatly appriciated ! :)

Comment: Update your post with the resulting html page. Also, where is your function called. Are you sure that it's called?

Comment: +1 what Vasiliy said, I would use Firebug in Firefox and see if some_data even exists, and if so what's in it.

Comment: Yes the function is called. If $.plot($("#placeholder"), [some_data] instead of some data has integer values, lets say 30 and 50, it prints the pie with those values. some_data however doesnt have any value... Maybe I'm parsing data in the wrong way?

Comment: rossdavidh I did as you suggested with firebug and it seems some_data actually has the data in it. there's what I got "var some_data = "1051.49" ". Now I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that your numeric data is being interpreted as a string.

From the [API.txt](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt):

> Note that to simplify the internal
>   logic in Flot both the x and y values
>   must be numbers (even if specifying
>   time series, see below for how to do
>   this). This is a common problem
>   because you might retrieve data from
>   the database and serialize them
>   directly to JSON without noticing the
>   wrong type. If you're getting
>   mysterious errors, double check that
>   you're inputting numbers and not
>   strings.

So either force your data to numeric types on the PHP side, or do it in javascript, perhaps with .`Number(some_data)`

Comment: Right on the spot! That's exactly where the error was. Thanks a lot Ryley!

Comment: One more thing, since I return an array of data now. Firebug shows some_data = "50" some_data = "30"... meaning it contains all the elements from the array I want, but the [Number(some_data)] from js doesnt pick up those values... Do I need to make a loop to retrieve it?

Comment: @Skittl3s, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101090/flot-pie-chart-with-php, essentially you should create a PHP array of your data and then use json_encode to send it to javascript, and then use $.parseJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ to decode it on the javascript side